# How to use `Pattern` and `Slot` to match n-element conditions?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, code-review

Extract the qualifying sublists.
– Condition: The elements are all in the `Reals` and greater than zero.

#### Question

If the sublist contains **many** elements, how can it be implemented with  the **disposable** code that as **short** as possible?
(`Select`, `Cases`, `Pick`, `Extract`, `Sow` – Use each at least once)

Extension:
What if I specify some elements that are **exceptional** as less than zero?

#### Code of My Question

```
list0 =
    {
       {-1., 0., 1.},
       {2., 2., 2.},
       {3, 3, 3},

       {  {4., 4., 4.},
          {5, 5, 5}  },

       Graphics3D[Line[{  {1., 2., 3.},
                          {2., 3., 4.}  }]]
    }
```

**(Condition 1)**
Initial filtering:

```
list = Cases[list0, {_Real, _Real, _Real}, -1]
```

Output:

```
    {
       {-1., 0., 1.},
       {2., 2., 2.},
       {4., 4., 4.},
       {1., 2., 3.},
       {2., 3., 4.}
    }
```

**(Condition 2)**
6 clumsy methods:

```
(* Way 1 *)
Select[list, #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] > 0 && #[[3]] > 0 &]

(* Way 2 *)
Cases[list, {x_, y_, z_} /; x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, -1]

(* Way 3 *)
Pick[list, UnitStep@Subtract[list, 0], {1, 1, 1}]~DeleteCases~{}

(* Way 4 *)
Extract[#1, #2] &[#, Position[#, {_?(# > 0 &), _?(# > 0 &), _?(# > 0 &)}]] &@list

(* Way 5 *)
Sow[#, #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] > 0 && #[[3]] > 0] & /@ list; // Reap // Last // Last

(* Way 6 *)
Sow[#, AllTrue[#, # > 0 &]] & /@ list; // Reap // Last // Last
```

Final output:
(Dropped `{-1., 0., 1.}`)

```
    {
       {2., 2., 2.},
       {4., 4., 4.},
       {1., 2., 3.},
       {2., 3., 4.}
    }
```

Grateful for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cases[list0, {__Real?Positive}, ∞]
```

> {{2., 2., 2.}, {4., 4., 4.}, {1., 2., 3.}, {2., 3., 4.}}

To save one character:

```
Cases[list0, {__Real?(# > 0 &)}, ∞]
```

> same output

**Update:**

> *What if I specify some elements that are exceptional as less than zero?*

For the case where the *j*th entry is the only negative entry, you can use the pattern `{Repeated[_?Positive, {j-1}], _?Negative,__?Positive}`

For the case where the *j*th entry is negative and others can be of any sign, you can use `{Repeated[_, {j-1}], _?Negative,___}`

Comment: Yes! *`{3,3,3}` and `{5,5,5}` are to be eliminated*. And how the "Extension"? (Modified post)

Comment: My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @ooo, can you give example illustrating what you mean by _"specify some elements that are exceptional as less than zero"_ ?

Comment: $\dots x_i>0 \dots x_j<0 \dots x_k>0 \dots$, and these "$x_j$"-type are also many. Will it need to use `#[[j]]` or still remains the better `_`?

Comment: @ooo, I think a pattern  like `{__?Positive, _?Negative, __?Positive}` should work.

Comment: That is where I am confused: how to exactly specify the position of the `_?Negative`? (Without using `#[[ ]]`)

Comment: @ooo, to say that  the `j`th entry is the only negative entry, you use the pattern `{Repeated[_?Positive, {j-1}], _?Negative,__?Positive}`; for the case where the `j`th entry is negative and others can be of any sign, you can use `{Repeated[_, {j-1}], _?Negative,___}` etc.

Comment: ... off course, you can also use `{__?(#[[j]]<0 &)}` .

Comment: Your comment is very essential to my modified post, so can you just copy and append them to your answer? Whatever, thank you so much!~